# Inject data in a function for a datePicker

Tags: ember.js

I am using [ember flatpickr](https://github.com/shipshapecode/ember-flatpickr) in my ember App.

It will be used in a component that also contain a date. I want to allow selection depending on the date.

To use a function with flatpickr I use the following working property:

```
dateDisabled: [function(date){
    let day = date.getDate()
    if (day & 1){
      return false;
    }else{
      return true;
    }   }]
```

This function test every date displayed by the date pickr and return a boolean to make the date selectable or not.

How can I pass a property to this function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats indeed funny, because [flatpickr itself takes a function inside the disabled array](https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/#disabling-dates). However  inside that function you don't have access to the ember controller context. So you probably should use an arrow function you create inside a computed property. this way you also have access to the model, and can modify your function if the model changes:

```
disable: computed('model.dateToEnable', function() {
  const dateToEnable = this.model.dateToEnable; // only for ember 3.1+, otherwise use .get
  return [date => date.getDay() === dateToEnable];
}),
```